# Wine won't install via Terminal

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, wine

Whenever I try to install wine this is what I get:

```
galien1@galien1-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get install wine  
[sudo] password for galien1:(Password)  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Package wine is not available, but is referred to by another package.  
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or  
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate  
galien1@galien1-desktop:~$
```

I don't know how to get wine!?!?!?!

Comment: Did you [enable the “universe” repository](/q/148638/175814)?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add the winehq repository follow there directions.
first we need multi-arch support for 32 bit wine prefixes.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

then add their repository:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key  
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

Update you package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you are ready to install.
I recommend a GUI package installer like aptitude or the software center since there are many versions of wine that can be installed (including testing and development stages).

To get the latest stable release, run:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-stable
```

See: [Installing WineHQ packages](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu).