# how do i install steamOS correctly and apt-repository help

Tags: repository

Hi there my name is Lucy. I love video games. I've been a PC gamer my whole life. 2 years ago I spent about $1200 on my new rig. I love it. I play games on the highest quality with a smooth 60 fps. I run over 120 mods on Skyrim without issues. its a good gaming rig except for one big major issue. My favourite game of all time and the reason i got my rig, does not work.

Specs:

- ASUS Crossblade Ranger
- AMD Athlon x4 880K
- AMD radeon Rx480 8g
- wind7 64 1T harddrive

My big issue is COD infinite warfare, but that's not what this post is about
SCROLL DOWN IF YOU WANNA SKIP TO MY QUESTION

All my games fine are except for COD. It keeps CTD with fatal error cannot read disc imagefile ### The game runs fine for about 5-10 min before it crashes, I tried to copy the "players2" folder and got it to work a handful of times without crashing. But then it starts again if i exit and reboot the game. I've re-installed over a dozen times, i tried on a different harddrive with a different copy of win7, but its always been the same thing. I actually got it working one time because an update error caused a temporary profile to load and for some reason it worked on that untill the updates fixed themselves. sometimes i get through one online match but that's the best i get out of it.
Sidenote*** COD has always been this way since i got it in 2016
and just recently ive had a couple of games bluescreen (skyrim/tekken7)
I suspect my hard drive is dying, i did buy it refurbished
Also, why cant i write a support ticket on steam do they even have support?

THE REASON FOR MY POST

I am beyond frustrated with my gaming console. So I decided to convert one of my drives to SteamOS YAY!
At least thats what i thought.
First of all, I had to DL the file 3 times from steam website because everytime it would DL with missing files. I had to manually put the whole thing together. Which could be the reason for my most recent failures.
Anyway the install was successful and steamOS booted and I got to the log in screen.
Mouse is working keyboard working.Network connected. BT was ready to go and syncing the controller was easy.
Only problem is that when i click "log in" nothing happens
SteamOS
WHEN I CLICK "LOG IN" NOTHING HAPPENS
There was no option to switch to desktop under system tab but i managed to get to desktop by holding alt-enter-tab has to be in that order
I searched for a solution and the only one i could find is that you need to install win32 ssl light which is dos fil and needs a program called 'wine' to open up so i tried download it I am new to linux btw, I find it appalling so far. Im doing this in hopes of getting COD working again
First i updated sudo apt-get update

Method 1 failed : I opened my terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
E: Unable to locate package wine1.5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.5'
```

Method 2 Install Aptitude Success
Tried to install from aptitude but it was very confusing i did go through the update process though u-U-g-g

Sometime between method 1 and 2 i read in on something about missing package files. I forgot to bookmark them and i couldnt get them to work but i remember it was in a forum that had a solution

Method 3 (getting there): [Wine won't install via Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933046/wine-wont-install-via-terminal)

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` ok
2. `wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key` ok
3. `sudo apt-key add Release.key` ok

But when i get to step 4 i get:

```
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo: apt-add-repository: command not found
```

I cant get the add repository command to work

i found these solutions
Fix 1- RESULT-FAIL?
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

```
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

What does that mean?

Fix 2 RESULT-FAIL

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
E: Unable to locate package software-properties-common
E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

Im literally stuck and cannot find a solution. Also sound is not working
I really dont want to restore this drive again. Im very annoyed but intrigued by linux and am very curious to see how games would run
it would be really nice if someone could go over the SteamOS install with me if not help fix this issue
I think i might try win8 or 10 on another harddrive
Thank you to anyone who read through this
All this for COD lol

Comment: We do not care about your life story, please edit your post with the problem you are having and the relevant error codes you are getting

Comment: Hi Lucy!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  We try to keep things as concise as possible here so that we can answer as many questions effectively as possible.  If there's alot of *technical* informtaion, then it's a good idea to put a TL;DR version at the top.  And generally, the less storytelling the better so we can see the real details of the question.  Can you please edit your question with this in mind? Thanks! :-)

Comment: Does all this have anything at all to do with Ubuntu in any way?

Answer (score 0):

lol, you're having a baptism in fire, welcome to linux. You at least have persevered and done remarkably well considering.

I'm not sure from your wall of text if you had problems installing software-properties-common, it looks like you did? if so did you update the system before trying to install it? Try doing this

```
apt-get update
apt-get install software-properties-common
```

My SoftwareProperties was installed from python3-software-properties not python-software-properties, so it looks like there was a name change at some point. I'd suggest you do

```
apt-get install python3-software-properties
```

That should hopefully sort those issues out for you. I'm not sure if that was all you needed, there really was a lot of text lol